# Check for nullable properties in a linq object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi have a linq object called Customer which is basically my Customer table in the database which has the following fields

```
Name Varchar(128) NOT NULL
Email Varchar(128) NULL
PostCode Varchar(16) NOT NULL
...a lot more fields
```

This object is bound to a model in mvc4:

```
public class EventModel{

    public Customer Customer {get;set;}

}
```

What I want to do is when this is bound to a model is add a custom validation object to check the properties of the object to validate the form in the view.  In exploring my linq object I can see there are properties such as Nullable and Server Data Type, the Name field for example has Nullable set to false and the Server Data Type is Varchar(128) NOT NULL.  From here I could potentially create the following:

```
[Required, StringLength(128)]
```

Does anyone have any thoughts on this or is there a simpler method?  A generic method to pass in any object to compare against the form would be ideal.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Fluent Validation](http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/) on your model, and have it check the elements of Customer entity

Alternatively you could modify the T4 template that generates your entities and have it generate partial classes so Customer would be a partial. Then you could create methods of validation on the other files that is the other partial associated with Customer.

Comment: This looks excellent and simple to use.  Do you know of a working sample code to see this in action?  I know there is extra code that needs to be written but worth it!

Comment: I just used the documentation section to learn. It's super simple and the examples are just as simple.

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CreatingAValidator&referringTitle=Documentation&ANCHOR#Chaining

Comment: If you end up using this as your answer don't forget to come back and mark it as the accepted answer, as it may take you a little time to learn and implement. So just don't forget. :) If it's not what you want good luck.

Comment: Looks good so far, is there a date property to define a date and do you know if you can supply custom messages in the rules?

Comment: Because dates can be many different ways there isn't a generic one that I have used. I haven't used the latest version so not sure. But you can use this to create one to your standard for how you store date.

http://fluentvalidation.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom&referringTitle=Documentation